# Can the phrase "change places" be used without an object?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Could a pupil say to their teacher: "Please can I change places" without specifying "with" someone else in the classroom?

Comment: Can I move to a different seat/place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  Nearly all prepositional phrases are optional and can be omitted if the context makes the meaning clear, or the information that would be in the phrase isn't needed.